# Scientific soundness of computer science papers

Tags: machine-learning, semantics, natural-language-processing

First of all, this question relates to an issue that affects several areas of science, but since StackExchange doesn't have a meta science section I'll make it specific to computer science, which is pertinent because the solution to the bigger problem may actually come from computer science.

In the context of the news that [Springer and IEEE published more than 120 nonsense papers](http://retractionwatch.com/2014/02/24/springer-ieee-withdrawing-more-than-120-nonsense-papers) my question is as follows:

What rigourous set of methods can we apply to the process of publishing scientific papers so that we can quickly verify the reproducibility of the experiments?

We already have systems like [Turnitin](http://turnitin.com/) that are highly efficient at detecting plagiarism, yet I don't know of any system that can score a piece of work on its *scientific soundness*.

Is there any ongoing work related to this? I found out about [Semantic Publishing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_publishing) whilst composing this question, but I have no idea what other approaches, if any, are being actively worked on.

Comment: This is just my humble opinion: the "science" in computer science is a misnomer. Technically, it's math. Meaning, it doesn't require proof by experiment, it's all about a priory knowledge. But, of course, it is possible to publish a nonsense mathematical proof, just like a scientific one. And all because of human error. I don't think there's any way to eliminate human error. PS. The first link is broken.

Comment: Even if it was all about math, I thought formal methods and formal verification exists specifically to verify formal specifications mathematically. In which case, why isn't it used throughout? PS: Thanks regarding broken link.

Comment: You may find some amusement in reading the report written for Multics system by Paul Karger and Roger Schell (it was famous once for establishing that "no system is safe"). Applied to this case: regardless of whether it is an error or a sabotage, it can be shown that it will not be possible to eliminate all such cases. I think that the better treatment for this event would have involved a) the number of all papers published, b) similar data for the last decade or two. What if these 120 papers don't even make a dent, or, perhaps, the trend is on decline.

Comment: I think this is off-topic as it's not a question about computer science *per se* but rather a question about computer scientists. If you make it less subject-specific, it would probably fly reasonably well at [academia.se], though check for duplicates first.

Comment: We have a relatively rigorous set of methods. It just happens to be imperfect (and perfectible), as all methods are, even "computational" ones. The misconception that material published in scientific journals is an expression of **The Truth** seems to be the problem here. It just isn't, and it was never meant to be that way. We have probably gone too far in turning scientific publishing into some kind of reputation market.

Comment: think this is an acceptable question & there are CS specific angles in the question/ possible answers.

Comment: Possibly this would be on-topic for Academia.SE? Perhaps there even is a similar question there already. Have you looked?

Comment: I agree with @vzn and his answer to this question adds valuable information which is relevant to the topic of Computer Science.

Comment: @Juho I was unaware of Academia.SE, so yes a similar question would probably be pertinent there too. Anyway, I think I made it on-topic given the example and the fact that the solution to the greater problem probably will involve a CS specific element. For starters the area of computer-aided peer-review probably will make a very interesting CS topic!

Comment: @AndréSouzaLemos Theoretical computer science is a formal science. Along with mathematics it's as close to establishing "truths" as you'll get. Even when formal methods cannot be applied, as a CS researcher you should produce sound knowledge upon which others can build, otherwise your work should be filed under fiction, right next to with the Holy Bible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a complex issue that affects all areas of science but has been getting higher visibility as the mainstream media has reported some cases in headlines. An answer seems to be better review systems. However, one might argue that nonsense papers are not *necessarily* a failure of the peer review system. All peer review systems must be human to some degree and all human systems are fallible/ subject to failure. any peer review system will have both *false positives* and *false negatives* in the sense of papers that were accepted but shouldnt be on 2020 hindsight, and papers that were rejected but were of acceptable quality. There is some increasing awareness/ sociological study of peer review systems. Cyberspace can in fact aid the process in some ways by increasing reviewers, increasing visiblity of reviews, adding rating systems, etc. and it can have downsides such as computational ease of creating fake submissions, increased AI capabilities to fool humans, etc.

An example of a CS specific peer review (meta-) analysis can be found in the recent [NIPs experiment](http://inverseprobability.com/2014/12/16/the-nips-experiment/) where peer reviewers were split into two groups, the same papers were given to each, and the overlap in acceptance/ rejection decision was measured. not unsurprisingly to many, results had quite high variance. Researchers overcome "false negatives" by resubmitting papers to other conferences. Unfortunately this NIPs experiment never seemed to be documented except across a lot of CS blogs and there is already some "link rot" of key links. It was announced informally at the conference and many insiders blogged on it including those participating. A full documentation might be considered "airing dirty laundry".

- [The NIPS Experiment](http://inverseprobability.com/2014/12/16/the-nips-experiment/)
- [NIPs peer review experiment](https://vzn1.wordpress.com/2014/12/19/the-nips-peer-review-experiment-and-more-cyber-zeitgeist/) / many links

Comment: I was unaware of the NIPS experiment. That is exactly the kind of meta-research that the scientific community needs, and since it's specific to Computer Science I will pick it as an accepted answer. Thanks.